# How to sort an array of objects based on a the length of a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects in javascript, each of which in turn has an array:

```
{
    category: [ 
        { name: "Cat1", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        },
        { name: "Cat2", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }, 
        { name: "Cat3", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to sort the array "category" based on the number of objects within the nested array "elements".

For example, after sorting, the above object might look like this (descending):

```
{
    category: [ 
        { name: "Cat2", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }, 
        { name: "Cat3", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        },
        { name: "Cat1", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }

    ]
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish this using javascript's sort() method.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `sort` method accepts a function in which you can define how to compare two elements. Here's the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/sort).

> **compareFunction**     Specifies a
>   function that defines the sort order.
>   If omitted, the array is sorted
>   lexicographically (in dictionary
>   order) according to the string
>   conversion of each element.

If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:

- If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b.
- If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
- If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.

#### Example code

```
var sorted_categories = original.category.sort(function (one, other) {
   //a - b is 
   //   0 when elements are the same
   //  >0 when a > b
   //  <0 when a < b
   return one.elements.length - other.elements.length;
});
```

Comment: It makes sense to cache the results of `elements.length` function as it will be called O(n * log n) times, i.e. a lot.

Comment: @Eli how can I make it Descending order.?

Comment: @Mrworldwide Switch one and other in the return statement like so `return other.elements.length - one.elements.length;`

Answer (score -1):

```
var category = [ 
        { name: "Cat1", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        },
        { name: "Cat2", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }, 
        { name: "Cat3", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }
];

function myAbcSort(a, b){
    if(a.elements.length > b.elements.length) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
category.sort(myAbcSort);
```

Comment: Wrong. You must return 0 for the case `a.elements.length == b.elements.length`.