# How to sort an Array of Array (2D Array) by first sub-array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to order an array composed by sub-arrays. 
The array have to be ordered by the first element of each sub-array element 
Example:

```
myArray = [ [1,0],[3,10],[2,5],[4,0] ]
```

desired output: `[ [1,0],[2,5],[3,10],[4,0] ]`

How can I achieve this in Javascript?
Thanks,Nk

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435228/sort-an-array-with-arrays-in-it-by-string

Comment: And you didn't try `myArray.sort()` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort`

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[0]-b[0]
})
```

Comment: Note that this will yield unexpected sort results if the operands are not integer values.

Answer (score 4):

```
var myArray = [ [1,0],[3,10],[2,5],[4,0] ];    
myArray.sort(); // [[1, 0], [2, 5], [3, 10], [4, 0]]
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/giyab/1/edit?js,console)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score -1):

**This your result**

```
myArray.sort(function(x, y){ return x[0] > y[0] });
```

**use this code hope ,it will work**

[Demo for this code](http://jsfiddle.net/5jVEH/)

Comment: Comparison functions should return -1 (negative), 0 or 1 (positive).

Comment: you can declare an array  ,in your console. myArray = [ [1,0],[3,10],[2,5],[4,0] ],
and then write this code you will get your sorted array.

myArray.sort(function(x, y){ return x[0] > y[0] });

Comment: A boolean return value may cause unexpected sort results.

Comment: i am adding the link in jsfiddle as "Demo for this code",check it once

Comment: No,its javascript code which works in any of the javascript compiler,you can check any one of online compiler and give me your output,if you will get any problem,,I hope it will work in any online compiler