# How do I pre-sort numbers and not screw up the formatting?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a custom function I am writing that will return an array of arrays:

```
function tester(col){
  var rows = [ // this gives me an error on sorting, so turn numbers to strings
    [4,2,3,"Tom"],
    [0,8,9,"Bill"],
    [5,7,1,"Bob"],
    [1,2,3,"Charlie"]
  ];

  rows = [ // turning numbers to strings screws up formatting
    ["4","2","3","Tom"],
    ["0","8","9","Bill"],
    ["5","7","1","Bob"],
    ["1","2","3","Charlie"]
  ];
   rows.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a[col].localeCompare(b[col]); // sort by column passed by user
  });
  return rows;
}
```

As noted, if I pass in numbers I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function localCompare in object
```

If I turn those numbers into strings I can sort but then the user isn't able to format the numbers...show more decimals, commas, turn them into percentages, etc. How do I resolve this?

EDIT:

I've tried the suggestion by Buzinas/Kriggs but it seems to do a lexical sort for numbers and negatives and others don't sort properly. I now have (notice the negative 4 and 750):

```
function tester(col){
  var rows = [
    [-4,2,3,"Tom"],
    [0,8,9,"Bill"],
    [5,750,1,"Bob"],
    [1,2,3,"Charlie"]
  ];

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a[col].toString().localeCompare(b[col].toString());
  });

  return rows;
}
```

Comment: Turn them back into numbers after sorting?

Comment: Some nasty tip:

```(0+'') === '0' // true```

Comment: @Roomy I don't follow

Comment: @kristen I mean adding an empty string (```''```) to a ```number``` or instance of ```Number``` will result a string, so following this ```(a[col]+'').localeCompare((b[col]+''))``` should be what you want. I didn't tested it, that's only a tip how to convert any number to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you want to sort by number if they are numbers, and by string if they are strings, you can do:

```
function tester(col){
  var rows = [
    [4,2,3,"Tom"],
    [0,8,9,"Bill"],
    [5,7,1,"Bob"],
    [1,2,3,"Charlie"]
  ];

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (typeof a[col] === 'number')
      return a[col] > b[col];
    return a[col].localeCompare(b[col]);
  });

  return rows;
}
```

Comment: ok, this is really weird. Now, the only column that will sort properly is column 0 (the first column).

Comment: @kristen he misplaced the `.toString()`, this is actually converting the whole row to a string then comparing it, that's why it seems only column A is indexing, it should be: `a[col].toString().localeCompare(b[col].toString());`. If you have no problem with hack'ish you can shorten it with `(a[col]+'').localeCompare((b[col]+''))`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks so much ;)