# Sort an array of number arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `arr` of four number arrays such as:

```
arr = [
    [4, 1, 3, 2, 0],
    [4, 2, 1, 3, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 1, 4],
    [0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
]
```

and I need to sort it to get:

```
arr = [
    [0, 2, 3, 1, 4],
    [0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
    [4, 1, 3, 2, 0],
    [4, 2, 1, 3, 0],
]
```

The number arrays can be larger, but the four arrays have always the same size. Sometimes it's necessary to compare more than the first and second elements of the number arrays to get the smaller.
I found the code below in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998413/1195909), but it is limited to the first two number array elements.

```
myArray=myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    retVal=0;
    if(a[0]!=b[0]) retVal=a[0]>b[0]?1:-1;
    else if(a[1]!=b[1]) retVal=a[1]>b[1]?1:-1;
    else if(a[2]!=b[2]) retVal=a[2]>b[2]?1:-1;
    return retVal
});
```

**EDIT**

In the output, the elements `arr[0][0]` and `arr[1][0]` are equal and smaller than the elements `arr[2][0]` and `arr[3][0]`. In a second level, the element `arr[0][1]` is smaller than `arr[1][1]`. In some cases there are many levels and I can't predict how much.

How could I implement it?

Comment: How is the second array (output) sorted? What is the rule?

Comment: In the output, in a first level, the `arr[0][0]` and `arr[1][0]` are lower than `arr[2][0]` and `arr[3][0]`. In a second level, the `arr[0][0]` is lower than `arr[1][0]`. I will explain in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the arrays until you find elements that don't match and return difference of first mismatch

```js
var arr = [
    [4, 1, 3, 2, 0],
    [4, 2, 1, 3, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 1, 4],
    [0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
]


arr.sort(function(a,b){       
   for(var i=0; i< a.length; i++){
     // if they don't match, return difference
     if(a[i] !== b[i]){
       return a[i] - b[i];
     }
   }  
   // if we get this far they are the same     
   return 0;
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
      for (i = 0; i < a.length); i++) {
           if (a[i] < b[i])
                return -1;
           if (a[i] > b[i])
                return 1;
       }
       return 0;
  });
```

Comment: `length()` is not a function