# Order array of objects with TypeScript by value

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I order this array of objects by object value? I’m using TypeScript.

```
console.log(this.items);
```

Output:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
{id: 3, ref: "P-201721", active: 1, visible: 1, weigth: 0.3, …}
{id: 4, ref: "P-201722", active: 1, visible: 1, weigth: 0.3, …}
{id: 1, ref: "P-201710", active: 1, visible: 1, weigth: 0.5, …}
{id: 2, ref: "P-201711", active: 1, visible: 1, weigth: 0.5, …}
{id: 5, ref: "P-201831", active: 1, visible: 1, weigth: 0.2, …}
{id: 6, ref: "P-201832", active: 1, visible: 1, weigth: 0.2, …}
```

I tried this, but the array maintains the same order:
*[Sort an array with arrays in it by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435228/sort-an-array-with-arrays-in-it-by-string)*

Comment: You want to sort by `id`?

Comment: Show what you actually tried.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. The highest voted answer to [the indicated duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) (2 minutes after the question was posted) contains *"It's easy enough to write your own comparison function"*. It shouldn't be different in TypeScript. Or if there is, it is definitely a TypeScript-only canonical question.

Comment: *"weigth"* is a misspelling of *"[weight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weight#Noun)"*.

Comment: That is one way to [earn the Lifeboat badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat?page=1): Answer a question that is very clearly a duplicate.

Comment: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value/56023953#56023953) deals specifically with TypeScript.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorting an array of objects can be a little tricky. You have to pass in a custom sorting function to define how you want to compare the objects. How else would .sort() know you want to sort by id? Maybe you want to sort by weight instead.

I've put together an example at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEReGE?editors=0012. You can replace the id references with any property if you'd like it sorted by that instead.

```
items.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.id > b.id) {
    return 1;
  } else if(a.id < b.id) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

If you are sorting by a numeric property you can use this shorthand:

```
items.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.id - b.id;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash) to achieve what you want. You can also use multiple sorting options by passing in the keys in the array inside the sortBy function.

```js
var data = [
{"id": 3, "ref": "P-201721", "active": 1, "visible": 1, "weight": 0.3},
{"id": 4, "ref": "P-201722", "active": 1, "visible": 1, "weight": 0.3},
{"id": 1, "ref": "P-201710", "active": 1, "visible": 1, "weight": 0.5},
{"id": 2, "ref": "P-201711", "active": 1, "visible": 1, "weight": 0.5},
{"id": 5, "ref": "P-201831", "active": 1, "visible": 1, "weight": 0.2},
{"id": 6, "ref": "P-201832", "active": 1, "visible": 1, "weight": 0.2}
]

var sort = _.sortBy(data, ["id","weight"]);

console.log(sort);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code works but I don't want to include 3rd party libraries, upvoted.