# How do I sort arrays in an array by string using custom alphabet in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Why this is not a duplicate: The "original" sorts by characters, not strings. I'm trying to sort by strings. This is a completely different question, it needs to be able to sort the entire string, not just one character.

I have this array:

```js
[
    ["ik", "p", "I; me", 1],
    ["pat", "pre", "plus", 1],
    ["qeol", "adj", "only", 1],
    ["nei", "adj", "not", 1]
]
```

I want to sort the array alphabetically by the first item, and using a custom alphabet where q is between n and o instead.

So, it should look something like:

```js
[
    ["ik", "p", "I; me", 1],
    ["nei", "adj", "not", 1],
    ["qeol", "adj", "only", 1],
    ["pat", "pre", "plus", 1]
]
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5435290) and tried to tweak it so that the q to go between the n and o, but nothing worked.

```js
words.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[0].toLowerCase() === "q" && a[0] < "n"? 1: (a[0] > b[0]? 1: -1);
});
```

I just tried random crap so of course nothing worked

How do I do this?

Comment: If the solutions there didn't work for you, show what you have tried ...

Comment: No, that sorts by char, this sorts by string.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a char and a string in javascript?

Comment: The question you linked only wants to sort by a single character, but mine needs to sort by a string.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not a big deal to extend comparing a single character to comparing muliple characters one after each other

Comment: But I know nothing about sorting in JS and stuff, that's why I asked this question

Comment: the above duplicate does not sort by characters, but for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a function for custom sorting by handing aover a string of characters an sort until the strings end.

```js
const 
    data = [["ik", "p", "I; me", 1], ["pat", "pre", "plus", 1], ["qeol", "adj", "only", 1], ["nei", "adj", "not", 1]],
    alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmnqoprstuvwxyz',
    sortBy = alphabet => {
        const order = Object.fromEntries([...alphabet].map((l, i) => [l, i + 1]));
    
        return (a, b) => {
            for (let i = 0, min = Math.min(a.length, b.length); i < min; i++) {
                if (a[i] === b[i]) continue;
                return order[a[i]] - order[b[i]];
            }
            return a.length - b.length;
        };
    },
    custom = (fn => (a, b) => fn(a[0], b[0]))(sortBy(alphabet));

console.log(...["ikb", "nqq", "ik", "pat", "qeol", "nei", "npo", "nop", "ika"].sort(sortBy(alphabet)));

console.log(data.sort(custom));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

A customized order can be established by utilizing a `Map` that assigns a unique index to each character in the alphabet.

```
const
   alphabet = Array.from(' abcdefghijklmnqoprstuvwxyz'),
   order = new Map(alphabet.map((char, i) => [char, i]));
```

This index can represent each item (array in your case) within a `TrueSet`.

```
const
    repr = array => order.get(array[0][0]),
    got = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING)
        .letAll(data)
```

Voilà! Your items are sorted according to your custom alphabet because the `TrueSet` sorts the items based on the provided `repr` function rather than the items themselves.
The online documentation of the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library offers an extensive exploration of the `representation` function's concept.

In `Node.js`, you can check validity of the proposed solution by:

```
import {TrueSet} from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import {ORDER} from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [
        ["ik", "p", "I; me", 1],
        ["pat", "pre", "plus", 1],
        ["qeol", "adj", "only", 1],
        ["nei", "adj", "not", 1]
    ],

    expected = [
        ["ik", "p", "I; me", 1],
        ["nei", "adj", "not", 1],
        ["qeol", "adj", "only", 1],
        ["pat", "pre", "plus", 1]
    ];

assert.deepEqual(got.toArray(), expected)
```

Importing `TrueSet` and `ORDER` into an `HTML` page requires execution of the script file `classifier.bundle.js` which is publicly avaible from the `jsdelivr` network. This script creates a global object `classifier` in the browser execution environment, hierarchically offering all the library's content, as follows.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ut8pia/classifier@0.0.1-19/trg/classifier.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  var
    TrueSet = classifier.queue.TrueSet,
    ORDER = classifier.global.ORDER
</script>
```

Comment: What does that code have to do with that library? Heck, does your "solution" even work?

Comment: @Anpang Yes, the solution is functional — I've tested it successfully. If you require clarification on any aspect, please, feel free to ask.

Comment: I clearly said I'm using client JS, not node.js.

Comment: @Anpang, to use the library in an HTML page, look at the updated answer.

Comment: I'd rather not have to download an entire library with megabytes of overhead just to use a single function that can also be done in vanilla JS like Nina Scholz's answer, thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, @anpang. If I recall correctly, the library is around 10K. Nevertheless, the crucial aspect is to feel comfortable with the code. Trust your aesthetic sense. Happy coding!

Comment: It's not an aesthetic sense, both are totally readable code, but even if it's really just 10K I'd rather have 0K overhead. Also, you can't even ping correctly, hah.