# Sort object key value by arrays length

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have an object named languages :

```
 ► JAVA : Array[1]
 ► C : Array[2]
 ► C#: Array[4]
 ► C++: Array[1]
```

I would like to sort this object by length (Desc) of each array :

```
► C#:Array[4]
► C:Array[2]
► JAVA:Array[1]
► C++:Array[1]
```

I have tried according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301856/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-a-the-length-of-a-nested-array-in-javas#answer-2301880)

```
    function myAbcSort(a,b){
        if(a.length>b.length){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.length<b.length){
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0
    }
    languages.sort(myAbcSort);
```

I'm getting :

```
languages.sort is not a function
```

Comment: Why downvote ? Could these people explain in order to improve ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object can not be sorted. You can create an array with key/values:

```
Object.keys(languages)
  .map(function(k) { return { key: k, value: languages[k] }; })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value.length - a.value.length; });
```