# Sort an array object descending orders (max length first.)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

By using this I can able to get the ascending order how can I get the reverse order max length first.?

```
{
    category: [ 
        { name: "Cat1", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        },
        { name: "Cat2", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }, 
        { name: "Cat3", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

My expected result is:

```
{
    category: [ 
        { name: "Cat1", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        },
        { name: "Cat2", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id },
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }, 
        { name: "Cat3", elements : [ 
            { name: name, id: id } ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my sort:

```
var sorted_categories = original.category.sort(function (one, other) {
   return one.elements.length - other.elements.length;
});
```

I want reverse result from this question:

[How to sort an array of objects based on a the length of a nested array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301856/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-a-the-length-of-a-nested-array-in-javas)

Comment: Have you tried doing `return other.elements.length - one.elements.length`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting arrays using for loop in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870961/sorting-arrays-using-for-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the operands of the subtraction.

Comment: Math - Pure Magic.

Answer (score 1):

```
 array = array.reverse();
```

Just reverse the array?